# SharePoint 2013: Hello World remote app using REST configuration

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, access-token

I'm trying to create a website that gets a list items from my SharePoint 2013 site. I found this 'Hello World' app that uses REST on MSDN, but i'm having some trouble configurating it.

In the configuration section says:

> To configure the Hello world remote app using REST sample, update the SiteUrl property of the solution with the URL of the home page of your SharePoint 2013 site.

I've searched all over the solution and haven't found that 'SiteUrl' property. Can somebody help me?

This is where I downloaded the app from: 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Hello-25f8c6f1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **BasicSelfHostedAppREST** project and hit **F4** (Show Properties)

[image]